# Is an LXC guest load average the same as the host's load average?

Tags: lxc, load-average

If I run `top` on the guest, the load average values seem to be exactly the same as running `top` on the host.

Is a Docker (LXC) guest's load average the same as the host's load average?

Comment: It seems this is a bug, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for `/proc/loadavg` - yes, it's the same.  The load average is read out from global variables.

```
      seq_printf(m, "%lu.%02lu %lu.%02lu %lu.%02lu %ld/%d %d\n",
              LOAD_INT(avnrun[0]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[0]),
              LOAD_INT(avnrun[1]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[1]),
              LOAD_INT(avnrun[2]), LOAD_FRAC(avnrun[2]),
              nr_running(), nr_threads,
              task_active_pid_ns(current)->last_pid);
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/loadavg.c#L13

```
void get_avenrun(unsigned long *loads, unsigned long offset, int shift)
{
        loads[0] = (avenrun[0] + offset) << shift;
        loads[1] = (avenrun[1] + offset) << shift;
        loads[2] = (avenrun[2] + offset) << shift;
}
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/proc.c#L79